# UK visa application, travel history before appointment

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I'm filling in my application for a UK standard visit visa. The question I have is about travel history.

Currently I'm not in the country I want to have the interview in. I intend to travel twice between submitting the application and attending the interview. I don't have a significant travel history, 2-5 Schengen border crossings and 5-7 visits to other countries.

Should I include those trips in the application already?

Comment: @DJClayworth exactly. Currently I'm not in the country I want to have interview in. I wouldn't count that a significant history, 2-5 Schengen border crossing and 5-7 visits to other countries.

Comment: @DJClayworth updated

Comment: I don’t imagine UKVI believes everyone stays home between applying for a visa and attending the interview.

Answer (score 1):

There is no point in adding entries on future travel in your visa application before you have traveled. Nobody knows exactly what will happen tomorrow and many travel plans do get aborted.

If you do not end up making those trips but had them on your application, it could be construed as misrepresentation/deception if discovered by an overzealous unreasonable ECO.

You don't need that hanging over your head, it leads to [a ban](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/deception-in-an-application-rfl04-paragraph-3207a/deception-in-an-application-rfl04-paragraph-3207a).

[UK visa refused under 320(7A) (deception) in 2009. Am I banned for 10 years?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/100464/uk-visa-refused-under-3207a-deception-in-2009-am-i-banned-for-10-years)

Alternatively you can actually hold off submitting an application until you complete those trips.

Comment: > Alternatively you can actually hold off submitting an application until you complete those trips.
This is a good point. Unfortunately I don't know when you usually get an appointment. Taking into account 3 weeks processing time I can really miss my trip to UK.

Comment: Well missing the trip is better than a ten year ban for deception/misrepresentation.

Comment: > Nobody knows exactly what will happen tomorrow and many travel plans do get aborted. 
I just wonder how is that supposed to look like when I get to the interview and the last entry to Schengen area wouldn't be mentioned in my application...

Comment: @UVV The application form does not ask about trips you plan to make - it asks about where you’ve visited (past tense). If you’re worried about it, you could mention your future plans in the comments section at the end of the application.

Comment: @Traveller that makes sense. Thanks, I follow your advice.