# How much can I visit the U.S. on a B-2 visa?

Tags: visas, usa

I'm a 24 year-old Australian. I got a B-2 tourist Visa to visit the U.S. for the first time and have just spent the full 6 months allotted on my arrival travelling around here and absolutely loved it.

I just wanted to know when would be possible for me to come back and spend more time here. I'm aware it's good to spend as much time out of the country as you do in it, and perhaps if I return they may either not let me in or give me less than 180 days entry.

So because that is all pretty loose in terms of what are the rules, I'd love to know if anyone has any stories of how soon after spending a long time here they came back? Particularly at my age, my nationality, length between visits, just anything about when you got the 180 days entry again, or if you got sent back, or how long between, or if you got in but less time, etc.

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: What are your ties to home? How are you planning to demonstrate non-immigrant intent in this scenario? You don’t want to risk being refused entry, that could haunt your travel plans for a very long time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [B1/B2 granted to UK resident for US visits. How long do I need to stay away between visits if I stay 6 months?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/118650/b1-b2-granted-to-uk-resident-for-us-visits-how-long-do-i-need-to-stay-away-betw)