# Ban under v3.7 appendix 320 7A UK

Tags: uk, deception

I applied for a visa to the UK in NOV 2016 and I got refusal under v3.6 (320 7A) because Uk immigration officer said in refusal letter that I made deception because I submitted 1 document that was my IELTS (English language proficiency) certificate which is non-genuine and also validation stamp is non-genuine. It’s mean I try to submitted a false document. 
But the truth is very different because my IELTS certificate is 101% genuine and I never try to submit any false representation in my application. When I got my refusal letter I was shocked what happend going on with me. Then I went to IDP IELTS Local office and they check my TRF and said me back it’s all genuine but they give me contact number and mail address of head office of IDP Australia first I called to local head office and after I mailed to them and I got that it’s totally genuine and validation stamp is also genuine. I got an email by IDP Australia that they said if I can pass him directly to my visa officer or by any mail address so then he can talk about my result but how to pass him to my visa officer I really don’t knew that. Even I don’t have any email I’d of UKVI.

I have my test date sheet and I had thumb biometric @ time of my examination for Ielts test. 
I really don’t know how the respected officer check out my certificate.

Now I made fresh application and I got same refusal again under 320 7A and they again mention my last points in refusal.

But really I’m saying very truly I didn’t submit any false document in my application.
Please help me in this meter

[image: refusal letter][image][image: New refusal][image: new refusal][image]

Comment: Please help me in this meter if any one has solution

Comment: I think your only realistic option is to talk to a lawyer specialised in UK immigration matters.

Comment: Your application has more problems than just the IELTS certificate. It is likely you would have been refused even if the certificate were not believed to be false.

Comment: @DJClayworth Yes, he would have still been refused, but he would not have been banned. The question of the genuine document is still something that he will need to clear up first. At this point a lawyer is pretty much required.

Comment: Yeah, I would focus very hard on removing the accusation of falsehood on your IELTS certificate.  If I filed again, I would open with "my application was rejected due to belief that my IELTS certificate was false. I obtained it entirely in good faith on the issuer's assurance it was valid.  Please see the notarized affadavit of the issuer's manager to the effect that they believe they are bona-fide and did in fact issue this ID number to me personally due to a test I took myself.  There would be no reason for me to falsify a test since I am competent at English." (which you are, in general).

Comment: Hi all and I’m very thanks full to all of you to answered me and I know I’m also refused even they didn't talk about my IELTS certificate but other hand I can clear all the point which are mention in refusal like about my salary and declaration of my course why I selected but the point of IELTS certificate which is totally false on me and I’m facing very impact on my career.

Comment: _What_ did you submit? Did you send a _photocopy_ or an original? https://support.cambridgeenglish.org/hc/en-gb/articles/202838356-Can-I-have-another-copy-of-my-IELTS-Test-Report-Form-TRF- clearly says you can request another original copy for visa purposes. If you sent a photocopy then yes, you sent a fake, this can't be helped, sorry. IELTS hammered this into us so hard I remember it thirteen years later! (Disclaimer: me leaving this comment doesn't endorse the moderation practices of this website but you really need all the help you can get.)

Comment: Hi @chx, I sent it original and after my refusal I again send my additional request IELTS TRF By IDP INDIA to embassy by directly to UKVI embassy but they didn’t received and return my TRF to IDP back..

Comment: You should read [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/77813/12065) and the attached answer, the answer being written by a very-highly respected poster on UK visa issues.  The summary is that to have any hope of dealing with this yourself, you needed to deal with this **at the time**, in 2016.  Having left it for three years, you basically now have no hope without high-end legal assistance from a specialist practitioner registered in the UK, and the costs of those run into the thousands of pounds.

Answer (score 4):

You could try submitting a Subject Access Request https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/requests-for-personal-data-uk-visas-and-immigration/request-personal-information-held-by-uk-visas-and-immigration to obtain details of the results of the document verification check https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/576713/Documentation-verification-v1.pdf that UKVI would have completed on your IELTS certificate.

Once you know more about why the document was deemed false you should be in a better position to decide how to apply again or whether to go to the expense of consulting an immigration lawyer.

Comment: By this answer I go through but it’s only for insider of UK living. It’s asking for UK address contact and UK post code.